# Overload Function call operator () for find_if

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have three classes

```
class A
class B
class C
```

I have two maps

```
std::map<A*, B*> myMap1;
std::map<A*, C*> myMap2;
```

and object pointers of A

`A* obj_ptr_A1 = new A;` and so on

I want to perform a find_if on both the maps for A*, so I wrote a functor and overloaded operator () twice as follows

```
class functor
{
    private:
        A* m_member;
    public:
        explicit functor(A* input) : m_member(input){}

        bool operator()(const std::pair<A*, B*>& iter) const
        {
             return (m_member->GetValue() == (iter.first)->GetValue());
        }

        bool operator()(const std::pair<A*, C*>& iter) const
        {
             return (m_member->GetValue() == (iter.first)->GetValue());
        }
};
```

where GetValue() is a member function of `A` returning an integer.
Usage:

```
if(std::find_if(myMap1.begin(), myMap1.end(), functor(obj_ptr_A1)) != myMap1.end())
{
    std::cout << "Found in myMap1" << std::endl;
}


if(std::find_if(myMap2.begin(), myMap2.end(), functor(obj_ptr_A1)) != myMap2.end())
{
    std::cout << "Found in myMap2" << std::endl;
}
```

This gives me compilation error 
`error C3066: there are multiple ways that an object of this type can be called with these arguments`
Is this overloading wrong?

Full code is here http://pastebin.com/DnUQKHPp It gives compilation error.

Comment: Try a `std::pair<A* const, B*> const&` etc. You could also use a function template, as the functions seem identical/similar: `template<class T> bool operator()(T const&) const { ... }`

Comment: Hmm can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Is there any inheritence among classes `A`, `B` and `C`?

Comment: @ontherocks Are classes B and C have a common base class?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No all the classes are independent classes. Working code posted in my question

Comment: The overloads of `operator()` are different in the pastebin than in your question :/

Comment: Yes, I corrected that with a new url

Comment: Well, [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0db5360033468501)

Comment: Is the code "fully working" now or do you have a compilation error?

Comment: @Snps The code I posted in pastebin has compilation errors

Comment: This works fine http://ideone.com/yMgOaO

Comment: @jrok Thanks, that worked. Should have given a closer look at the Visual Studio error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (Without testing)

```
template <class T>

class functor
{
    private:
        A* m_member;
    public:
        explicit functor(A* input) : m_member(input){}

        bool operator()(const std::pair<A*, T*>& iter) const
        {
             return (m_member->GetValue() == (iter.first)->GetValue());
        }
};

if(std::find_if(myMap1.begin(), myMap1.end(), functor<B>(obj_ptr_A1)) != myMap1.end())
{
    std::cout << "Found in myMap1" << std::endl;
}


if(std::find_if(myMap2.begin(), myMap2.end(), functor<C>(obj_ptr_A1)) != myMap2.end())
{
    std::cout << "Found in myMap2" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problems that I see in the OP's post, and there are cleaner ways to write this.  Your answers are usually excellent, are you tired?

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that if you make the comparison `Argument` a template parameter instead of `A*` you can do different key-value combinations in the map, provided you make the `functor::operator()` a template for the `Iterator`.

This is how the functor looks like:

```
template<typename Argument> 
class functor
{
private:
    Argument m_member;
public:

    functor(Argument a)
        : 
            m_member(a)
    {}

    template<typename PairIterator>
    bool operator()(PairIterator iter) const
    {
        return (m_member->GetValue() == (iter.first)->GetValue());
    }
};
```

This is the functor generator:

```
template<typename Argument>
functor<Argument> make_functor(Argument const & a)
{
    return functor<Argument>(a); 
}
```

and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd00531f96511479) is the complete online example.

Comment: @MooingDuck: maybe. I like it because it gets rid of overloading and works for different combinations, that's why I posted it... maybe someone finds this useful.

Comment: I was unclear.  This answer is good _advice_ (ergo, no downvote), it just doesn't seem like it answers why his code isn't working at all.  This answer simply replaces the broken code with much better working code, with no explanation for what was broken.

Comment: @MooingDuck: All clear. Should I remove the answer or address the error?

Comment: I'd be happier if you stuck a sentence at the top stating what's wrong with his code, and then say "However, templates would greatly enhance your `functor`, as shown here..."

Comment: Cool. Will do, but first thing tomorrow morning, I'm dead tired.